# X wont start after upgrade to 18.10

Tags: xorg, 18.10

### PROBLEM:

After upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10, X wont start on 2 of my older DELL computers until I manually run:

```
init 3
init 5
```

### DETAILS:

The boot process ends on a text screen with all the boot messages.  The last few lines of which are:

```
[  OK  ] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

At this point everything seems to hang.  So I ssh from another computer, and observe the following:

- the files `/var/log/Xorg.*` are empty (I cleared them prior to rebooting) so it doesn't look like any attempt has been made to start X.
- htop shows 0% cpu usage, and just a few hundred mb of ram used (both computers have 16G of ram)
- if I run `sudo init 3` then the boot messages are cleared away and I finally get a console login screen
- if I run `sudo init 5` then X finally starts and I get the graphical login screen

Both computers with this problem are older DELL desktops with different nvidia cards:

```
> ubuntu-drivers devices
...
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : G84 [GeForce 8600 GT]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
```

and:

```
> ubuntu-drivers devices
...
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : G98 [Quadro NVS 295]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
```

I'm up-to-date with packages:

```
> cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=cosmic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.10"

> sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I too have this issue.  Right now, I need to add a 3 at the end of the linux boot line, and then I see login:,  after logging into the console, startx then brings of the desktop.  Working to determine how to correct this issue.

Comment: I was worried that Ubuntu 18.10 might have an issue with this old hardware, so I did a complete re-install of one of the computers where I was experiencing this issue, and everything now works correctly on that one computer.

Comment: 18.04 is an LTS release which will be supported for much longer time than 18.10, so one shouldn't be upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10 unless you need some very specific features which are missing in 18.04 and are present in 18.10. That said, I wonder if your problem has anything to do with the switch to Wayland. As far as I recall Wayland was the default in 17.10 but was deemed not quite ready for LTS yet for which reason it was announced that 18.04 would not be using Wayland, but 18.10 would.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this is happening.  In the meantime, here is how I decided to work around it:

```
cd /etc/cron.d/
sudo vi workaround_to_start_x
```

Copy-and-paste the following:

```
# see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093808/x-wont-start-after-upgrade-to-18-10
MAILTO=""
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot root    sleep 30 ; init 3 ; init 5
```

Save the file, then reboot the device.  30 seconds after boot, X now starts up.

(No idea if the 30 second pause is necessary, but I figured I would give it a half decent chance of starting up whatever else needs to start up at boot time.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The machine froze at different lines it was booting when loading 18.10. Alt+F2(F3) fixes that by going into console mode and typing startX. But it loads with default drivers ( I have GTX980 with latest drivers). For some reason pressing Alt+F2 on Ubuntu logo stage(that is where it usually freezes and goes into console mode  and there gets stuck at different lines every other time) works for me and loads Nvidia drivers. The rest just works fine.